# Singleton pattern doesn't work in Xamarin multi-platform project MVVM

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, design-patterns

I have a C# (Xamarin) solution structured like this:

```
 Solution
 ┣  Main application
 ┃ ┣  ViewModel Project
 ┃ ┃ ┣  ...
 ┃ ┣  Android Project
 ┃ ┃ ┣  MyActivity.cs
 ┃ ┃ ┣  ...
 ┃ ┣  iOS Project
 ┃ ┃ ┣  ...
 ┗  Multiplaftorm Library
   ┣  Android-specific Library Project
   ┃ ┣  MyModuleAndroid.cs
   ┃ ┣  ...
   ┣  iOS-specific Library Project
   ┃ ┣  MyModuleiOS.cs
   ┃ ┣  ...
   ┣  Shared Library Project (.shproj)
   ┃ ┣  MyLibrary.Shared.projitems
   ┃ ┣  Service.cs
   ┃ ┣  Factory.cs
   ┃ ┣  IMyModule.cs
   ┃ ┣  ...
```

The module requires very device specific initialization, that I must do in the platform specific part (I make the example with Android)

```
// MyActivity.cs

[Activity(Label = "", WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustPan]
public class MyActivity
{   
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        MyModuleAndroid.Init(this); // I need an Activity as input
    }

...
```

The Init involves a singleton pattern:

```
// MyModuleAndroid.cs

public class MyModuleAndroid
{
    public static void Init(Activity activity)
    {
        Factory.GetInstance().DoSomething();
    }
}
```

```
// Factory.cs

public class Factory
{
    private static Factory instance;

    public static Factory GetInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            // only if no instance existing, I create a new one
            instance = new NFCModuleFactory();
        }

        return instance;
    }
...
}
```

Then, the instance is used inside the Service (shared project) that is called always from view model. But... here is the problem: the first time I try to access the instance (the second, after the initialization), **I found it's null**, so the singleton re-creates a new instance! If I call again from service the instance is mantained, but I already lost all my initalization data.

How can I solve this?

As a workaround, I noticed that If I structure my library like this, so by creating a fourth project that manages the factory (so the singleton), it works perfectly:

```
 ┗  Multiplaftorm Library
   ┣  Android-specific Library Project
   ┃ ┣  MyModuleAndroid.cs
   ┃ ┣  ...
   ┣  iOS-specific Library Project
   ┃ ┣  MyModuleiOS.cs
   ┃ ┣  ...
   ┣  Shared Library Project (.shproj)
   ┃ ┣  MyLibrary.Shared.projitems
   ┃ ┣  Service.cs
   ┣  Standard Project (.csproj)
   ┃ ┣  Factory.cs
   ┃ ┣  IMyModule.cs
   ┃ ┣  ...
```

As I said, in this way it works... but I really cannot understand why! :-(

UPDATE:
Accordingly to the debugger, GetInstance is called several times during the use, and the `new` is called exactly twice (one when called from MyModuleAndroid and one when called from Service).

Comment: Not shure. Could there be multiple threads involved?

Comment: I exclude it's a thread issue, several seconds pass between one `GetInstance` and the next.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Assuming correct locking, there are only two ways `new NFCModuleFactory` can be called twice:

a) `Factory.instance` gets set to `null` somewhere, between the two uses. OR

b) There are TWO DIFFERENT COPIES of `class Factory` in use.

Re "b", are you sure the project diagram you show is correct?

One way to get the symptom you describe is for `Factory` to be included TWO PLACES in your code. Either by copying that source file somewhere else, or by importing the `shproj` project DIRECTLY into your main project (separate from importing the android project).

Either of those will result in two different `Factory` classes. Each of which is a singleton, but they are unaware of each other.

Your revised project layout avoids this, by moving `Factory` out of `shproj` code.

---

Long-term advice: learn how to accomplish your goals w/o ANY use of `.shproj`.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

- You've used breakpoints or debug.writeline to verify that the calls to getinstance are happening in the desired order?
- Also, have you verified that `new` is indeed done twice?

If so, implement a `lock` around the contents of `GetInstance`. To make sure the first one finishes, before the second one is allowed to proceed:

```cs
public static Factory GetInstance()
{
    lock (_instanceLock)
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            // only if no instance existing, I create a new one
            instance = new NFCModuleFactory();
        }

        return instance;
    }
}

private static object _instanceLock = new object();
```

Comment: Thank you @ToolmakerSteve, I just tried the solution with "lock" but unfortunately the result doesn't change. The call order is not so important, by the way, I add some info to the original post about what happen when I call the GetInstance.

Comment: Updated with an explanation.

Comment: I think you got the point, as the .shproj was used directly by the ViewModel project (which must be platform independent, so it doesn't know if my project is Android or iOS), I didn't imagine it will create in fact a totally independent copy.